# Including two ranges for a log2 value re: affy and microarrays

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm working in affy on an expression set, and am trying to narrow down a pairwise correlation by some criteria to create a PairComp...a log fold change less than -1.5, or greater than 1.5. I can't seem to do both in one command. I'm also filtering by a p-value less than 0.05, and there must be a minimum of 2 samples per chip.

My code is as follows:

```
mfap5.data.exprs<-exprs(mfap5.data)

mfap5.filtered<-pairwise.filter(pair,
min.present.no = 2,
present.by.group = "T",
fc=log2(1.5),tt=0.05)
```

I've no idea how to add the criteria "OR" in other words, how do I specify that I want genes that have a log fold change below -1.5 OR above 1.5?

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Comment: Just an idea, not sure if its applicable but can you use the absolute of the value you calculate as the fold change? Then you only have to filter for 1.5 not both.